# How to open embedded excel sheet in Powerpoint presentation using c#

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint slide in which an embedded excel object is present, which is embedded in the following way: insert-object-create from file-browse-display as icon. 
I'm trying to open this excel sheet programmatically using c#.
The problem I'm facing is that I'm receiving the error: 
"Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: OLEFormat (unknown member) : Invalid request.  The window must be in slide or notes view.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.OLEFormat.Activate()"
I have tried changing the viewtype to slide as follows:
  presentation.Application.ActiveWindow.ViewType = PowerPoint.PpViewType.ppViewSlide;
But this doesn't seem to help and I'm receiving the same error.

`

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(@"D:\test.pptx");
foreach (var item in presentation.Slides[1].Shapes)
                    {
                        var shape = (PowerPoint.Shape)item;
if(shape.Name.Contains("Object")) {
 presentation.Application.ActiveWindow.ViewType = PowerPoint.PpViewType.ppViewSlide;
                presentation.Application.Activate();
                presentation.Application.ActiveWindow.Activate();
 shape.OLEFormat.Activate();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)shape.OLEFormat.Object;
}
}`
```

This is the code which I'm using.
Could anyone please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

It makes the job simple while working with clean presentations using Office.Interop lib. But it gets tricky when we try to access and edit OLEObjects in the presentation.

Try this!:

```
PowerPoint.OLEFormat ole = shape.OLEFormat;
ole.Object.Activate();
Excel.Workbook workbook = ole.Object;
```

this will create a workbook instance. 
Note: OLEFormat.Object is dynamic type, no need of type cast the object. but yes you need handle Error when the type cast fails.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.